# How do I get an instance of KX_PolygonMaterial in Blender?

Tags: textures, python, blender

I've got a question concerning using Python in Blender's Game Engine.

Before I start I want to state that I'm trying to change the color of an object in Blender's game engine. To do this, I'm attempting to find a way to update the texture of the object (I basically want two or three states, red, (yellow), green).

What I'm doing right now is:

```
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene();    
pingMeter = scene.objects['Ping Meter'];
mesh = pingMeter.meshes;
materials = mesh[0].materials;
material = materials[0];
```

However, when I do `print(material.__class__.__name__)` it outputs `KX_BlenderMaterial`. Shouldn't I be getting `KX_PolygonMaterial` if I'm running the Blender Game Engine? Is there anyway to change color or texture with `KX_BlenderMaterial` because I can't find anything in the documentation. Can I get an instance of `KX_PolygonMaterial` out of the code above?

...or should I just take a different approach all together?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I'm using Blender 2.65 which uses Python 3 in case anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined a way to change the color of an object's material in Python with Blender 2.65.  Before my approach above I simply tried something like:

```
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene();
pingMeter = scene.objects['Ping Meter'];
red = mathutils.Vector((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
pingMeter.color = red;
```

However, this produced no change to the color of the material (should've turned red, and the object was properly lit as well).  I found that there has to be an option checked under the materials menu of the object which is `Object Color`.  After checking this box the ping meter successfully change to red in the game.

Additionally, another method I attempted was to get the mesh of the object, get the material of the mesh, and change each vertex color of it.  This did not work either, however I speculate that if the `Vertex Color Paint` option is checked in the materials menu that it would.  I have not tested this though.